# How to run pyspark script without show the running process in the window

Tags: python, pyspark, pyscripter

I have a pyspark file test.py in a server and I want to run this file with an argument(teo).

```
spark-submit --driver-memory=32g --executor-memory=32g test.py teo 2>&1 test.logs.
```

Although when I am running it starts to show the whole process in the window but I do not want that. Instead of that I want to store all the running process in a .logs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like below

```
spark-submit --driver-memory=32g --executor-memory=32g test.py teo >> test.logs 2>&1
```

This will redirect the terminal output to `test.logs`